# How to exclude auto-mapping nested objects with C# AutoMapper (Version=7.0.1.0)?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am having an issue when my auto-mapper is mapping my object and **it's nested complex objects**. For example, i have this class Report which looks like this:

```
 public class Report
 {
      public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

      public virtual string Title { get; set; }

      public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

 }
```

Also, i have a model for this object which looks like this:

```
public class ReportModel 
{
      public Guid Id { get; set; }

      public string Title { get; set; }

      public StatusModel Status { get; set; }
}
```

The Status class looks like this:

```
public class Status
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and the StatusModel class is same as Status class.

My mapper looks like this:

```
var cfg = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
cfg.CreateMap<Status, StatusModel>()
         .ForMember(x => x.Title, o => o.MapFrom(s => TranslateValue(s.Title))).ReverseMap();
cfg.CreateMap<Report, Report>().ReverseMap();
```

My problem is that in many cases, when i am using the auto-mapper for the class Report i need the Status title to be translated, which is okay with this code. But in some specific cases, when i am using the auto-mapper for the class Report, the title of the Status object should not be translated.

So, i need to tell the auto-mapper to stop auto-mapping the nested objects for some specific cases. Is there any solution for case like this?

PS: The version of the AutoMapper is 7.0.1.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to resolve the special cases from the source object (in your example, the Status object), you can use the [PreCondition()](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html) option in ForMember:

```
var cfg = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
cfg.CreateMap<Status, StatusModel>()
         .ForMember(x => x.Title, o => 
         {
             o.PreCondition(s => s.Somefield == 42);
             o.MapFrom(s => TranslateValue(s.Title))
         }).ReverseMap();
cfg.CreateMap<Report, Report>().ReverseMap();
```

Comment: Unfortunately i can not use this solution, because there is no attribute in the class which indicates if the PreCondition is true or false.

Comment: but you wrote *But in some specific cases* if you do not write what is the "specific cases" then noone will anser you